# How to find a query to replace this 'not in' query exactly in spark

Tags: sql, apache-spark

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE A.key1 NOT IN (
        SELECT B.key1
        FROM B
        )
    AND A.key2 NOT IN (
        SELECT B.key2
        FROM B
        )
```

This query has very poor performance in Spark. So I wanted to replace to other query. Is there any idea about that? ( ex. left-anti join )

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM B
        WHERE B.key1 = A.key1
        )
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM B
        WHERE B.key2 = A.key2
        )
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged on StackOverflow. Please try to elaborate a little as to why this is a correct answer to the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the code if you wish to do it by left anti-join. Left anti-join will keep only records from the left table with no corresponding match from the right table. It also only displays columns from the left table.

```
sqlContext.sql(
  """SELECT A.* FROM A
    | LEFT ANTI JOIN B
    | ON A.key1 = B.key1  AND A.key2 = B.key2
  """.stripMargin)
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged on StackOverflow. Please try to elaborate a little as to why this is a correct answer to the OP's question.

Comment: @philantrovert: Thanks for the tip. Edited the answer. Will take care in future as well.